# Magento prototype.js and stuck in checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, upgrade, ce-1.9.2.0, prototype-js

After upgrading our shop to 1.9.2 the checkout doesn't work. The whole process continues, but when I click "place order" it gets stuck in "submitting order information".

Before I can see these errors in Chrome.

[image]

Would be really great if you could help. Been searching on the web for days. I would be really grateful for every idea.

Comment: Can You first try to rename your theme checkout.xml and and checkout folder in your theme template then clear cache and check it.

Comment: @[IT0055](http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/43164/it0055) if you have a similar problem, please post it as a new question using the [Ask Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button instead of editing this question.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var quoteBaseGrandTotal = <?php echo (float)$this->getQuoteBaseGrandTotal(); ?>;
    var checkQuoteBaseGrandTotal = quoteBaseGrandTotal;
    var payment = new Payment('co-payment-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/savePayment') ?>');
    var lastPrice;
//]]>
</script>
```

As we can see, the `quoteBaseGrandTotal` variable may come from this template. Please, check this variable in your custom template again.